# Как сделать, чтобы при уменьшении в мобильном разрешении, смещался обзор в определенный участок картинки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Чтобы при уменьшении экрана на картинке на определенном участке увеличивалась картинка? Допустим, чтобы при мобильном разрешении был участок на картинке в нижнем левом углу или (на левой, на центральной или на правой стороне, или на определенном отрезке?

Comment: попробуйте кратинку поставить background: url(); и задавайте background-size и background-poisition. как вариант абсолютное позиционирование внутри элемента и двигайте как хочется

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать css [медиа-запросы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Попробуйте поизменять маштаб страницы [тут](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/full/PyoQga/).

```
.img {
  float: right;
}


@media screen and (min-width:1152px){
  .img {
    float: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1552px){
  .img {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Comment: немного не то,допустим есть бэкграунд в боди,и при разных медиа запросах,чтобы картинка,не просто поместилась в другой угол,а именно при увелечении была левая часть фона,а не она же только меньше или центр этой же картинки был,чтобы при увеличения,увелечение проходило бы в конкретную точку или область